# Meteor helper of template not firing when data changes?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have the following on my client side:

```
Template.cellular.helpers({
    getCells: function() {
        console.log("getting cell list");
        things = cellItems.find({owner: Meteor.userId(), FileId: "someId"});
        console.log(things);
        return things;
    }
});

<template name="cellular">
    <div id='cellPane'>
        <div id='data'>
            {{#each getCells}}
                <div id="{{_id}}" >
                    <div class='celldesc' contenteditable="true" display="block">
                            {{description}}
                    </div>
                    <div class='cellval' contenteditable="true" display="block">
                            {{vals}}
                    </div>
                    <div class='cellformula' contenteditable="true" display="block">
                            {{formula}}
                    </div>
                </div>
            {{/each}}
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

When I insert the following, it does not seem to fire the helper showing the console statement but I see flicker of the template being updated and then removed. What is happening? How can i correct it?

```
{owner: Meteor.userId(), FileId: "someId", description: "something", vals: "0", formula: "something else"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding a document with `FileId: "someId"` but your helper is doing a `find()` on *`dynaFileId: "someId"`* therefore the document you just inserted is not included in the cursor.

Comment: oops. i just edited my code and forgot to change the dynaFileId to FileId before posting here. i will edit my question...

Comment: If that's not the problem then please include your *publish* and *subscribe* code. It's likely that your publication excludes the document you are inserting.

Comment: `cellItems.allow({'insert': function (userId,doc) { return true; }, 'update': function (userId,doc) {return true; }});` is the server code. `cellItems = new Mongo.Collection("cells");` is the common code in lib. I am a newbie and not sure i am doing it right.

Comment: Are you still using autopublish?

Comment: When i use `meteor remove autopublish` it says autopublish is not in this project. Do i have to use pub-sub to get data from server? Cant i query the common Collection cellItems to insert() and then find() data?

Comment: Yes, you need to publish the *cellItems* collection on the server and subscribe to it on the client. To verify first, do `meteor add autopublish` and see if your code behaves as expected.